# How to update values in pandas column based on a changing URL?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm attempting a small project to learn about data scrapping.

I've set up a for loop to pull similar information from multiple pages of a website. More specifically, I'm changing the URL using an f-string so that I can pull the same information for each individual states page. I want to add the new URL as part of the data frame so that I can go back, and spot check my results later.

My initial attempt looks something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

for i in list_of_states:
    url = f'url_here{i}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'table_class_here')
    
    table_titles = soup.find_all('th')
    table_headers = [title.text.strip() for title in table_titles]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = table_headers)
    
    column_data = table.find_all('tr')

    for row in column_data[1:-1]:
        row_data = row.find_all('td')
        individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = individual_row_data

    state = url[x:y]
    df['state'] = state
```

After running the code I realized that my final 2 lines of the for loop are resetting the state column in my data frame to a new constant every single time.

I've spent some time on this website looking through other people's questions that are similar in nature but have been unable to find a general solution that I can apply to my situation.

I'm sure I could just pull each states information separately and union the data frames together, but I'm really hoping I can avoid that.

Comment: The ```for loop``` will reinitialize your ```df``` everytime. you will need to save the ```df``` at the end of each loop into a list/dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert the data frame to a list and add the new information with every single loop.

```
list = []

for i in list_of_states:
    url = f'url_here{i}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'table_class_here')
    
    table_titles = soup.find_all('th')
    table_headers = [title.text.strip() for title in table_titles]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = table_headers)
    
    column_data = table.find_all('tr')

    for row in column_data[1:-1]:
        row_data = row.find_all('td')
        individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = individual_row_data

    state = url[x:y]
    df['state'] = state

    df_to_list = df.values.tolist()
    list.extend(df_to_list)
```